# How to use custom operations with tensorflow server

Tags: docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, custom-operator

What is the ideal way to have tensorflow model server recognize my custom operation?

I have a custom operation written following this guide:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op

I'm able to use the opp by calling `tf.load_op_library`, but when I try and and run `tensorflow_model_server`

```
tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 \
                        --model_name=mymodel \
                        --model_base_path=/serving/mymodel
```

I get the following error about being unable to find my opp.

> tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:37] Loading servable: {name:
>   mymodel version: 1} failed: Not found: Op type not registered 'MyOpp'
>   in binary running on c37a4ef2d4b4.

Comment: As a side note I asked a similar question on tensorflow's custom-op repo https://github.com/tensorflow/custom-op/issues/3

Answer (score 4):

Here are the things that I wanted to do with my op:
    - generate python wrappers
    - add op too the pip package
    - have my operation linked to tensorflow so tensorflow-serving could execute the operation

I placed my op in tensorflow/contrib/foo. Here is what the source tree looked like

```
.
├── BUILD
├── LICENSE
├── __init__.py
├── foo_op.cc
├── foo_op_gpu.cu.cc
└── foo_op.h
```

My `__init__.py` file had the import for the generated wrappers

```
from tensorflow.contrib.sampling.ops.gen_foo import *
```

I added an import in the `tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py`

```
from tensorflow.contrib import foo
```

Here is my `tensorflow/contrib/foo/BUILD` file:

```
licenses(["notice"])  # Apache 2.0
exports_files(["LICENSE"])

package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_py_library")
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_gen_op_libs")
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_gen_op_wrapper_py")
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_kernel_library")

tf_kernel_library(
    name = "foo_op_kernels",
    prefix = "foo",
    alwayslink = 1,
)
tf_gen_op_libs(
    op_lib_names = ["foo"],
)
tf_gen_op_wrapper_py(
    name = "foo",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        ":foo_op_kernels",
    ],
)
tf_custom_op_py_library(
    name = "foo_py",
    srcs = [
        "__init__.py",
    ],
    kernels = [
        ":foo_op_kernels",
    ],
    srcs_version = "PY2AND3",
    deps = [
        ":foo",
        "//tensorflow/contrib/util:util_py",
        "//tensorflow/python:common_shapes",
        "//tensorflow/python:framework_for_generated_wrappers",
        "//tensorflow/python:platform",
        "//tensorflow/python:util",
    ],
)
```

Here are the tensorflow bazel files I had to touch to get it working.

- `tensorflow/contrib/BUILD`

  - Add `foo_op_kernels` to `contrib_kernels` deps
  - Add `foo_op_lib` to `contrib_ops_op_lib` deps
  - Add `foo` to `contrib_py` deps
- `tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD`

  - Added my python target to `COMMON_PIP_DEPS`
- `tensorflow/core/BUILD`

  - Added my kernels to `all_kernels_statically_linked`. I might have gone overboard with this one, but It worked.

Here are the tensorflow serving bazel files:

- `WORKSPACE`

  - Change `org_tensorflow` to be a `local_repository` pointing to my tensorflow rather than a google's `tensorflow_http_archive`

Then I modified: `tensorflow_serving/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel-gpu` to clone my versions of tensorflow and tensorflow-serving.

Comment: Do you have any elaborate explanations on these steps? A complete example may be better? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a doc describing how to do that: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/custom_op

The bottom line is that you need to rebuild tensorflow_model_server with your op linked in.
tensorflow_serving/model_servers/BUILD:

```
SUPPORTED_TENSORFLOW_OPS = [
    ...
    "//tensorflow_serving/.../...your_op"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your op lib in BUILD file where you want to call it?

Comment: Thank you that advice got me started. I had to do a few more bazel things to get everything working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tensorflow as a submodule or local_repository to use the custom macros in the repo for your ops.

Comment: yifeif, would you be able to kindly provide an example of this?

Comment: I would also like to see an example of this approach :) Sounds cleaner/easier.